# str.startswith() on list of numbers as strings gives strange result

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate over a list of numbers in order to check if the items start with 1 or 2, and append to another list a 1 if the former is true, and a 0 if the latter is true. The numbers vary a lot in size, so an `if else` statement would be a hassle.

Sample of the list to be iterated over (contains 2640 items, going up to 2111210):

```
list1 = [1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 11110, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 11210]
```

The closest I've come so far is a method to check the first "letter" of an item in a list that contains strings. So, I tried converting `list1` to a list strings and using `str.startswith()` to check if the items start with 1 or 2:

```
list1 = str(list1)

list1 = '[1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 11110, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 11210]'

y = []

for i in list1:
    if i.startswith('1'):
        y.append(1)
    else:
        y.append(0)
```

The resulting `y` list gave a strange result, and I can't figure out why:

```
y = [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Am I completely on the wrong track here? Any tips to achieve the task is appreciated.

Comment: Are the elements string or int? In your post seems int.

Comment: The indentation in your code is currently a syntax error. We can try to guess what's indented how, but you really need to take care to properly copy/paste code which depends on whitespace to be represented accurately. What works for many people is to copy/paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K (but this doesn't work in the mobile version of this site as far as I know).

Comment: Originaly int, but converted to string. Didn't include the conversion in the code here, will fix.

Comment: Are you wondering why Python does this, or how to fix your code so it does what you say you want to do?

Comment: Some thing look wrong in your code: indentation is incorrect and you are trying to apply the method `startswith` to an integer. Fixing those silly mistakes, [your code gives the expected results](https://repl.it/repls/DarkgreenFrequentScaup)

Comment: Edited the post to contain the correct information now.

Comment: @tripleee both! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the list to a string containing the `repr()` of this list.  Then you are looping over the characters in the `repr()`.

```
>>> list1 = [1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 11110, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 11210]
>>> list1 = str(list1)
>>> list1
'[1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 11110, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 11210]'
```

So, your loop is examining `'[', '1', '1', '1', '1', ','`...

A much simpler solution is to just temprarily convert each element to `str` inside the loop.

```
y = [1 if str(elt).startswith(('1', '2')) else 0 for elt in list1]
```

This uses a more condensed construct called a list comprehension. If you find it hard to read, it's basically equivalent to

```
y = []
for elt in list1:
    if str(elt).startswith(('1', '2')):
        y.append(1)
    else:
        y.append(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I accepted your answer since it contains a nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the elements to `str`, not the `list` itself. Otherwise you are iterating over individual chars in one long string. The following should do the trick for the initial list of integers:

```
y = [int(x.startswith('1')) for x in map(str, list1)]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Should have noticed the ' ticks at the beginning and end of the list.